# Nuget package publish is publishing lower versions intermittently

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to publish Nugets to my Nuget server that are to be used in my application. But when I see the version that it's publishing, sometimes it's lower than the latest version on the server because of which the update is not visible in Packages Console Updates tab. This is happening intermittently. Any ideas  why will be appreciated.

We use CLI to publish the packages and below are the steps. 1. cd .<project_name> 2. ...nuget\NuGet.exe pack -Build -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects 3. ...nuget\nuget.exe push *.nupkg -SkipDuplicate -source http:/****** 4. del *.nupkg

Comment: What is your process for publishing your package? Are you using the CLI? Please provide more context to your issue.

Comment: We use CLI and below are the steps.
1. cd .\<project_name>
  2. ..\.nuget\NuGet.exe pack -Build -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects
  3. ..\.nuget\nuget.exe push *.nupkg -SkipDuplicate -source http:/******
  4. del *.nupkg

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for responding to my comment. It would help others if you could add this information to the question itself; good questions provide substantial relevant context. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You don't mention how you specify your version